# What to do with negative Chow test?

Tags: change-point, chow-test

I have just done a Chow test on a regression in order to see whether there is a structural break. I am a bit stumped however as my Chow test returns a negative number. Now what do I do?

More specifically, this expression (from the Wikipedia [entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chow_test) for the Chow test):

$\frac{(S_c-(S_1+S_2))/(k)}{(S_1+S_2)/(N_1+N_2-2k)}$

turns out negative for me.

EDIT: It turns out it was a simple programming error.

Comment: Does your regression has an intercept? Omitting intercept sometimes can cause problems. Also could you post reproducible example? It is clear that you made an error, as @onestop pointed out, but with example available it may be possible to point out where the error is exactly.

Comment: Cheers! Thanks for your edit. Simple programming errors are the biggest enemy of scientific progress :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've made a mistake somewhere in your calculations. It's not possible for the sum of the squared residuals from a single regression using the combined data to be less than the sum of the sums of squared residuals from the regressions using the two separate sets of data.